# Equation guesser to get an output when an array of integers given

Tags: ruby, algorithm

The function takes two arguments. An array of integers and a number which should be the result obtained using the array of integers and basic operators (addition / subtraction / multiplication / division ) . The algorithms can make different guesses and then eventually find the sequence with lowest number guess needed.for example.

```
 equation_guesser = EquationGuesser.new([1, 2, 3, 4], 24)
```

Now `guesses` function guess different permutations of `1,2,3,4` with operators `+ , - , * , /` to get the result 24. Make the algorith such that number of guesses needed is less.

```
equation_guesser.guesses
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10 
1 * 2 * 3 * 4 = 24 
Guesses: 2 Best Guess: 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 = 24
```

Comment: That's a great problem but you didn't answer the most important question: **What have you tried**? I don't see any code here to help you with. Hint: Try looking into [`Array#permutation`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-permutation).

Comment: I have no idea , how to go ahead with this problem. From the looks of the it involves permutation of integers and operators.Then the operators have to be applied on the integer permutation .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network. Because this question is about finding an algorithm, it belongs IMO to [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/). If am implementation of an algorithm wasn't working than this would be the right place.

Comment: @spickermann There are lots of algorithms questions on this site. What's the algorithm tag for?

Comment: @DaveGalvin: The existence of a tag doesn't tell if questions about on-topic. There are tags like hardware and security for example, both topics have dedicated sites. A pure hardware question or a discussing about some password hashing algorithm would be off-topic too. But most important: The OP will get better answers in a shorter period of time when he posts his question on a site that is more appropriate.

Comment: Cross-post: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/63849/755, http://stackoverflow.com/q/39682533/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.  @spickermann, if you're going to suggest another site, please make sure to tell people not to cross-post and suggest they delete their question here before posting elsewhere.  Also, I see you don't seem to have an account on CS.SE.  Please don't suggest a site if you're not familiar with its quality standards.

Comment: What is your question?  I don't see a question here, just a copy-paste of an exercise.  What did you try? Where did you get stuck? What approaches have you considered?  We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that.

Comment: The fact that it's on-topic on another site, or would get better answers on another site, doesn't make it off-topic here.  See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287400/781723, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260769/160917, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204287/160917.  Also, questions about algorithms aren't necessarily off-topic here.  See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271842/781723 and [help/on-topic] (note: "software algorithm").  (Cc: @DaveGalvin).